# Add WaterMark(Text) On Video In Asp.net Core Mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

i want to add watermark on videos in asp.net core,

i use this code :

```
    NReco.VideoConverter.FFMpegConverter wrap = new FFMpegConverter();
    wrap.Invoke("-i D:\\input.mp4 -i D:\\inputImage.png -filter_complex\"overlay=10:10\" D:\\Output.mp4");
```

but show this error, whats, problem ?

**TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.HttpContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.**

Comment: System.Web.HttpContext is part of .Net Framework while you are using .Net Core. Please justify this.

Comment: can i add .netframework to .net core project ?

Comment: No, but you can migrate your project.

Comment: i dont want change to .netframework , do you have any tutorial for add water mark on video?

Comment: Try to use any other SDK like VisioForge or DirectShow. But it's a little bit complicated to do this.